# How to exclude default Keys on Parse-Server REST API

Tags: key, parse-server

****By Default Parse Server return all keys when you query Certain Class including  "createdAt" & "updatedAt".

But what if I want to exclude those default keys in my query result I have tried following but no luck.

If you pass nothing in "keys=" parameter then it will return default keys only. If you pass Single key then it will return along with default keys as well****

http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/TodoList?excludeKeys=createdAt

http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/TodoList?Keys=

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported as SDK's rely on those fields.

A possible solution would be to use the aggregate framework.

**Note:** Project with -1 is supported in mongo 3.4+

```
const pipeline = [
 { project: { createdAt: -1 } },
];
const query = new Parse.Query(TestObject);
await query.aggregate(pipeline);
```